# Getting the Canvas element to Cover my header/nav

Tags: html, css, canvas

Im trying to get my canvas to cover my header and navigation panel but it's just stacking on top even though it's got a greater Z-index. Is I use position absolute, it goes over the elements I want but it does not align properly. The canvas will start maybe at the halfway point which I don't understand. Shouldn't it inherit the positioning/alignment from the topWrapper rules?

HTML

```
<div id="topWrapper">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="850px" height="194px"></canvas>
    <a href="index.html">       
        <header id="top_header"></header>
    </a>    
    <nav id="topnav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="video.html">Trailers</a></li>
            <li id='adminPage'><a href="admin.html">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#topWrapper {
    background-color:#0d0d0d;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto; left:0px; right:0px;
    float:clear;
    background-image: url('images/headfoot/bg5.jpg');    
}
#top_header{
    width: auto;
    height: 120px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 2px 0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background: url('images/banner.png') center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
#topnav{
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
    width: 100%;
}
#canvas{
    background: green;
}
```

I tried using Absolute positioning on the canvas element which places itself over like I need but then the alignment doesn't work:

[image]

Comment: I created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LfXME/ but still do not understand exactly what the problem is.  Could you explain it with more detail?

Comment: @mwcz Yea sorry If I wasn't detailed enough. I need the canvas to Cover the header and the nav. So right now it's the same size as both but I need it to be on top of the logo and navigation. When I add position absolute to it, it does what I want but it does not align properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set

```
#canvas{
    position: absoulute;
    left: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LfXME/2/

In your example, it is not aligned properly because `#topWrapper` has `text-align: center;` property, and that forcing `#canvas` to start from center.

Comment: Yea that works. Thanks. I solved it earlier using margin-left:-425px but that solution seemed really ugly. I like this much more.

Answer (score 1):

**Working fiddle based on your code:** http://jsfiddle.net/PZU9F/

This will solve your problem as far as you have explained based on your code.

If you provide more details the solution could be optimized and be more efficient.

```
#canvas{
    margin-bottom: -129px;
    background: green;
}
```